# How to establish OneToMany relationship between two model where primary key and foreign key is a String in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I am trying to create OneToMany Relationship between Airport and AirportComments model by taking "ident" from Airport model class as a primary key and foreign key in AirportComment model class. Using Mysql DB.

```
**Airports Model Class**

`import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;

@Entity
@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Airports {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

        
        @Id
        @OneToMany
        private String ident;
        
        private String type;
        private String name;
        private String lattitude_deg;
        private String longitute_deg;
        private long elevation_ft;
        private String continent;
        private String iso_country;
        private String iso_region;
        private String municipality;
        private String scheduled_service;
        private String gps_code;
        private String iata_code;
        private String local_code;
        private String home_link;
        private String wikipedia_link;
        private String keywords;
        
//      
//      private AirportComments comments;
        
}`
```

```
**AirportComments Model Class**

import java.sql.Date;

import jakarta.persistence.CascadeType;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToOne;
import lombok.Data;

@Entity
@Data
public class AirportComments {

    
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private long id;
    
    private long threadRef;
    private long airportRef;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="airportIdent", referencedColumnName = "ident")
    private String airportIdent;
    
    private Date date;
    private String memberNickname;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
}
```

**I am getting error like**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-08-21T11:39:46.411+05:30 ERROR 27228 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Association 'com.airport.Model.AirportComments.airportIdent' targets an unknown entity named 'java.lang.String'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1155) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:436) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.airport.AirportCaseStudyApplication.main(AirportCaseStudyApplication.java:13) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Association 'com.airport.Model.AirportComments.airportIdent' targets an unknown entity named 'java.lang.String'
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1952) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1901) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1808) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:328) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.6.Final.jar:6.2.6.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1817) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766) ~[spring-beans-6.0.11.jar:6.0.11]
    ... 21 common frames omitted
```

i am expecting establish connection between String ident from Airports class and String airportIdent from AirportComments class.

Answer (score 0):

Airports class:

```
@Entity
@Data
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Airports {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;


    @Id
    private String ident;

    private String type;
    private String name;
    private String lattitude_deg;
    private String longitute_deg;
    private long elevation_ft;
    private String continent;
    private String iso_country;
    private String iso_region;
    private String municipality;
    private String scheduled_service;
    private String gps_code;
    private String iata_code;
    private String local_code;
    private String home_link;
    private String wikipedia_link;
    private String keywords;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL ,mappedBy = "airports")
    private List<AirportComments> airportComments;

}
```

AirportComments class:

```
@Entity
@Data
public class AirportComments {


    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Id
    private long id;

    private long threadRef;
    private long airportRef;

    @ManyToOne
    private Airports airports;

    private Date date;
    private String memberNickname;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
}
```

The One-to-many relationship which you are trying to create in your question is wrong, the above code should work.

Comment: Thanks, Akhil for trying to help me. This is working but I want to bind the one-to-many relationship between Airports.ident and AirportComments.airportIdent.
Means an Airport.ident should contain multipleairportComments .

Comment: Yes , won't the above structure solve your requirement?
You can also change the foreign-key column name